# ssh eval "$(ssh-agent -s) returns Illegal variable name

Tags: ssh, eval, ssh-keygen

Why does the `eval` statement return

> `Illegal variable name`

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Illegal variable name.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `$ eval "ssh-agent"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command is

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

(no quotes!)

Background: `ssh-agent` sends two lines of code to `stdout`

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-xxxxxxxxx/agent.nnnn; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=22414; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

where `/tmp/ssh-xxxxxxxx/agent.nnnn` is a file used as a socket to connect to the agent, and the second line contains the PID of the agent process.

`$(command)` contains those two lines and `eval` takes them and uses them to create/execute two commands
 - result: you have two environment variables telling every process how to connect to the agent.

Comment: This also gives "Illegal variable name." for me

Answer (score 1):

In .csh or .tcsh, the syntax to insert the results of a command into another command like eval is backquote, so the necessary command seems to be

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

That sets the two environment variables and prints the agent PID rather than giving an "Illegal variable name" error